# Restclient returning Uni<Void> causes ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145

Tags: quarkus

I have a restclient with a method returning a `Uni<Void>`. When calling this rest endpoint I am getting the following exception. What have I done wrong here? How am I supposed to code for rest endpoints that return void? I am doing a `call` with this endpoint in the middle of a chain

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/octet-stream and type class java.lang.Void: javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003145: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/octet-stream and type class java.lang.Void
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:199)
```

In the pom.xml I have `quarkus-resteasy-jackson` `quarkus-rest-client` `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny`

Comment: Are you using `quarkus-resteasy-mutiny`?

Comment: @geoand Yes! I added more info about my pom.xml dependencies in the question

Comment: This sounds like a bug - can you open an issue please?

Comment: @KTrum, @geoand was there a ticket for this eventually?
My workaround for this is to add explicitly the content-type header on the requested endpoint.
Example: `Response.ok().header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build()`
Of course this implies that you own both side resources.